# Wordpress - can't enqueue my custom-script after all other scripts

Tags: wordpress

On wordpress, using GeneratePress free template, I'm trying to push my custom script after all others.
The big problem is that all the scripts of a plugin ([Visual Portfolio](https://github.com/nk-o/visual-portfolio)) are always loaded at the very end, after my scripts.

I tried to put a very high $priority parameter in the add_action() functions but it doesn't work.

```
function register_scripts_and_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js.js', null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts_and_styles', 99999 );
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false )` you need `array()` or `array('jquery')` after the file name, not `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's idea, js and css files in WP use different technique to figure out in what order js\css files should be loaded.

here's function

`wp_enqueue_script('custom-js',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js.js', array('js-handle-of-some-dependency','js-handle-of-some-other-dependency'), true);`

Each script has it's handle, it's first argument to this function, in your case it's `custom-js`.

Based on digging into plugin's [code](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-portfolio/) it's main js has handle `visual-portfolio`

So you can just enqueue your script with setting it's handle as dependency.

And final solution will be:

```
function register_scripts_and_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js.js', array( 'jquery', 'visual-portfolio' ), '1', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts_and_styles' );
```

I've also added `jquery` as dependency as I guess you are using jQuery in your js code, you can remove it if not.

I've also set version to `'1'` - it's a query string version which will be applied to your JS code so when you do update and move code live you can force user's browsers to load a fresh one just changing version here.

And see last argument `true`, it denotes that your script will be injected in footer.

If your code relies not only on `main.js` of this plugin you might need to add more dependencies as this plugin enqueues bunch of scripts, see whole list of them in `/wp-content/plugins/visual-portfolio/classes/class-assets.php` from line 350, at the end of `register_scripts` method of class defined in this file. So you really can put exactly all script's handles on which your custom js code relies and WP will figure out right order of linking those files to page for you.

Happy codding :)

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail !

Your explanations are very clear and complete. I was struggling to clearly understand how enqueue function worked (args, etc), and especially how to find 'handles' names in plugins code (even more thanks for this).

You are awesome!

Thank you again for your time and I hope this will be helpfull for others.
Have a nice day, take care.